# Read csv file and remove duplicate from csv file and sum specific column

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2rYl.png)
above image part no 2, 8 is found duplicate value, so how to sum "Qty" value,  see part no 2 Qty sum value will be = 4 and part no 8 and Qty value will be 16

bellow is my expected result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZDW2.png)

I need result like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA52J.png)

Comment: Conceptually you might use a dictionary based on the key "Part" to help sum things up.  However, please don't use pictures of code and please show us an attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty easy with pandas. I am not too familiar with the library, but I found that this should work:

```py
import pandas as pd

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df = df.groupby(["part", "description", "LotNumber", "ExpirationDate", "Location", "LocationGroup"])["Qty"].sum()
df.to_csv("result.csv")
```

> You can change the file to read from and the output file as well. It was also quite hard to see the name of one of the columns, so make sure that the names are right.

There should be a better way to do this, but as mentioned I am not that good at pandas.

And to use pandas you will need to install it from pip: `pip install pandas`

Comment: it's working with the help of group by condition but result.csv is not generating

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Or is it just that the file is not created? @Deepak